# Where is Sphinx template attribute for the Builder object in the docs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx

I am currently working on a small extension to use jinja templates in my sphinx documentation and as i started i came across [this](https://www.ericholscher.com/blog/2016/jul/25/integrating-jinja-rst-sphinx/).

For anyone that doesnt want to click the link, the code is as following:

```py
def rstjinja(app, docname, source):
    """
    Render our pages as a jinja template for fancy templating goodness.
    """
    # Make sure we're outputting HTML
    if app.builder.format != 'html':
        return
    src = source[0]
    rendered = app.builder.templates.render_string(
        src, app.config.html_context
    )
    source[0] = rendered

def setup(app):
    app.connect("source-read", rstjinja)
```

This works great, but I wanted to change it a bit and understand how it works. So as usual, I went to the docs.

Based on the [Sphinx extensions API docs](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/index.html#important-objects) the application object carries a builder attribute which links to [StandaloneHTMLBuilder](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/builders/index.html#sphinx.builders.html.StandaloneHTMLBuilder)  (assuming we are creating the docs with HTML) which inherits from the [Builder](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/builderapi.html#builder-api) class.

So all good so far.

From there, it takes the templates attribute from the Builder. Where is the templates attribute defined in the docs? I have spent multiple hours looking around, but to no avail.

You might have noticed [Builder](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/builderapi.html#builder-api) has a TODO saying "expand this" so is it just not up to date, or am I just going completely wrong about this.

To be clear, the application works completely fine and does what It's supposed to. I am just lost in the docs on where the templates attribute is described. As it isn't in the [Builder](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/builderapi.html#builder-api) section or [StandaloneHTMLBuilder](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/builders/index.html#sphinx.builders.html.StandaloneHTMLBuilder) section.